# help with convert in java for android

Tags: c#, java, android

I have this code in C#, I have tried to convert him to Java for android, but I get an error in doing so.

This is the C# code:

```
sum = "";
string Num = "123ABC";
int i, j;
string TmpOT;
for (i = 0; i < Num.Length; i++)
{
    TmpOT = Num.Substring(i, 1);
    j = Convert.ToChar(TmpOT);
    j = (j / 10) + (j % 10);
    if (j >= 10)
    {
        j = (j / 10) + (j % 10);
    }
    sum += j.ToString();
}
```

And this my attempt at converting it to Java:

```
for (i = 0; i < Num.length(); i++)
{
    TmpOT = Num.substring(i, 1);
    j = Convert.ToChar(TmpOT);
    j = (j / 10) + (j % 10);
    if (j >= 10)
    {
        j = (j / 10) + (j % 10);-
    }
    Sum += String.valueOf(j);
}
```

the error is in line 5 - convert to char

Comment: how do you know the codes not a her?

Comment: please be more specific on what error you are encountering

Comment: You should at least add what kind of error you are getting and which row causes the error.

Comment: For some reason `string Num` doesn't make much sense to well, me, but probably to others too. Also did you try to use `someString[0]` instead of `Convert.ToChar(someString)`? Seems to make more sense. Also, this honestly looks like horrible code...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `Convert.ToChar(...)` in Java. You need to find the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

The first method in the java method listing for the String class:
[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Java `Convert.ToChar(TmpOT)` try `(int)TmpOT` as `Convert.ToChar(...)` does not exist in Java.